# How to select all nodes with the same name for different parent nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I have the following xml:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
  </person>
  <children>
    <person>
      <name>Jack</name>
    </person>
  </children>
</root>
```

Is it possible to select both persons at once? Assuming that I don't know that the other person is in the children tag, they could easily be in the spouse tag or something completely different and possibly in an other child. I do know all persons I need are in the root tag (not necessarily the document root).

Comment: @_Thijs Wouters: You have accepted a wrong answer. The answer by @nonnb is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
//person
```

or

```
//*[local-name()='person']
```

to find any `person` elements in the document, but be careful - certain xsl processors (like Microsoft's), the performance of double slash can be poor on large `xml` documents because all nodes in the document need to be evaluated.

**Edit :**
If you know there are only 2 paths to 'person' then you can avoid the `//` altogether:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/person | /root/children/person">
    <outputPerson>
        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()" />
    </outputPerson>
</xsl:for-each>
```

OR namespace agnostic:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='person'] 
  | /*[local-name()='root']/*[local-name()='children']/*[local-name()='person']">
```

Comment: +1, useful suggestions. I would caution though, re: `performance of double slash is poor on large xml documents`, that it depends on the XSLT/XPath processor. This is such a common operation that a good processor builds indexes by element name to make this very fast.

Comment: P.S. I assumed that by `name` you meant the name of the element you're looking for, i.e. `person`. The OP is not actually looking for the element called `name`.

Comment: @Lars - thx for feedback -the outputPerson was just to give OP an example - he didn't give an output xml schema. I had a bad experience with using // in BizTalk 2009 Maps - processing documents ~100MB spiked the CPU usage. In my case I was just being lazy - replacing the // with the full path avoided the issue, and 'no //' is now a coding standard for our BizTalk maps.

Comment: Some of my friends who work on XQuery internals have told me there was a time when // was slow for many engines, including theirs, and explicit paths were faster.  Now that they have changed their internal representation, some of them tell me, the reverse is true and they wish the idea that // should be avoided hadn't spread so widely.  So the iron law of performance remains true:  if it matters to you, measure *your* alternative solutions on *your* data running *your* processor, and take every general rule, even from well informed people, as interesting folklore.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen thanks - I will heed your advice in future and qualify accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**In Petar Ivanov's answer the definition of `//` is wrong**.

Here is the correct definition from the **[XPath 1.0 W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)**:

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

Answer (score 2):

```
//name
```

will match both, no matter where they are in the xml tree.

> `//` Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp))

Comment: @Petre: Always provide any definition from the normative source only. In your answer the "definition" of the XPath pseude-operator `//` is wrong.

Comment: w3schools is notorious for such garbage. Two of the "expressions" in the table where this definition appears aren't even expressions. And the definition doesn't make sense.

Comment: Moreover, the OP asked for `person` elements, not `name` elements. Sad that this answer got accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

root//person

So you search for persion only in root element

Answer (score 1):

As nonnb stated double slash's performance are poor on large xml documents.

So `//name` would do the trick but might bring up much more elements that you expect.
Plus imagine within your root element you have some elements that are not persons that might have descendants element with the name *name*, according to your question you don't want to bring them up, `//name` will bring them up.

You should affine your context-node at max so performance wise your XPath will be optimal.

For this precise document I would use

```
/root/descendant::person/name
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: `descendant::` is no better than `//` for performance. In fact `//` is just an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. So your proposed expression is equivalent to `/root//person/name`.

Comment: But am I not at least not loading person ? I know it won't change much but syntactically it feels more accurate - according to me.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you're asking whether `/root//person/name` performs better than `/root//person`, it seems unlikely: the processor has to first find all `person` elements descended from `/root`, then find each one's child `name` elements.